# how i can get format number with group sparator in listview

Tags: java, android, arrays

i am confused to find out how to make a number format with a sparator group like 1000 to 1,000 in a textview / listview, here i submit my coding snippet.

```js
private void showEmployee(){

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(konfigurasi.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_ID);
                String lembar1 = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1);
                String lembar1rp = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1RP);
                String lembar2 = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR2);
                String lembar2rp = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR2RP);
                String lembar3 = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR3);
                String lembar3rp = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR3RP);
                String keterangan = jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_KETERANGAN);

                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_ID,id);
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1,lembar1);
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1RP,lembar1rp);
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR2,lembar2);
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR2RP,lembar2rp);
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR3,lembar3);
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR3RP,lembar3rp);
                employees.put(konfigurasi.TAG_KETERANGAN,keterangan);
                list.add(employees);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                TampilSemua.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{konfigurasi.TAG_ID,
                             konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1,
                             konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1RP,
                             konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR2,
                             konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR2RP,
                             konfigurasi.TAG_KETERANGAN},
                new int[]{R.id.id,
                          R.id.lembar1,
                          R.id.lembar1rp,
                          R.id.lembar2,
                          R.id.lembar2rp,
                          R.id.ket});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

the example of the value I want to change is the value that is in lembar1, lembar1rp

please help me, to solve this problem ..
thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the String.format() method to add the commas.  The input must be numeric to use this, so use Integer.parseInt() to convert it to a number first.

Change the lines:

```
String lembar1 = String.format(jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1);
String lembar1rp = String.format(jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1rp);
```

into

```
String lembar1 = String.format("%,d",Integer.parseInt(jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1)));

String lembar1rp = String.format("%,d",Integer.parseInt(jo.getString(konfigurasi.TAG_LEMBAR1rp)));
```